# How to replace value of a variable using grunt-text-replace?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gruntjs

I want to replace the value of a variable which is string in nodejs. I am using grunt as my task runner. When I run grunt, I want to replace the value of var a, b, c which is url according to the different task that I run. These are my statements:

```
var a = 'www.xyz.com',
var c = 'localhost:4000'
```

When I execute grunt-text-replace, it replaces the 'a','b','c' instead of replacing their value. How to fix this?

Comment: Can you share the code that you have right now? It will be easier for people to help you, when you share what you've tried so far.

Comment: This is my code,

Comment: @batman Please paste the content of the grunt-text-replace target in your gruntfile.

Comment: I think your questions could look *much* better with only a little [improvement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163). Look, how well it looks after my edit. Also you could do it.

Comment: @I-LOVE-2-REVIVE All capital nicks don't look very well on the first spot. I suggest to become simply "I-love-2-revive" or similar.

Comment: @peterh Kudos I guess! You're not wrong... but effort

Comment: app.js ----
var base= 'https://someurl.com/';
var host= 'localhost';
---gruntfile.js
replace: {

      beta: {

        src: ['app/scripts/app.js'],
        overwrite: true,
        replacements: [{
          from: /base = [A-Za-z0-9': "\/.]*/g,
          to: 'base = "https://newurl.com/"'
        },{
          from: /host = [A-Za-z0-9': "\/.]*/g,
          to: 'host = "rainer"'
        }]
      }

Comment: It is not working properly, as the values are not getting replaced and instead of it, keys are replaced. Maybe there's some issue with regex and I tried doing that as well.